# I am not sure what I am doing wrong with my UICollectionView

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

Here's my problem.  I am trying to follow a guide online on how to do this swift project.

https://www.credera.com/blog/mobile-applications-and-web/building-a-multi-directional-uicollectionview-in-swift/

It seemed to work for him and I can't find anything about it in the comments.  Please help!  If I could ask for more than just an answer so I could reason through my future problems, that would be appreciated!

Here are my two files:

```
//  CustomCollectionViewController.swift

import UIKit

let reuseIdentifier = "customCell"

class CustomCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView?.dataSource = self
        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource
    func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        //#warning Incomplete method implementation -- Return the number of sections
        return 10
    }


    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        //#warning Incomplete method implementation -- Return the number of items in the section
        return 10
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! CustomCollectionViewCell

        // Configure the cell
        cell.label.text = "hi"
        return cell
    }

    // MARK: UICollectionViewDelegate


}

//  CustomCollectionViewCell.swift

import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class CustomCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    func setup() {
        self.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
    }
}
```

Here is the error log, FYI I filtered some names.  I think it says something along the lines of pulling a cell that is out of range.  But, out of range of what?  It's not pulling from an array or dictionary and the cells are created dynamically.

```
2019-12-30 22:10:46.031790-0500 Project_Name[2813:268267] [MC] Lazy loading NSBundle MobileCoreServices.framework
2019-12-30 22:10:46.032990-0500 Project_Name[2813:268267] [MC] Loaded MobileCoreServices.framework
2019-12-30 22:12:06.928652-0500 Project_Name[2813:268267] <UIView: 0x10170d810; frame = (0 0; 768 1024); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x1c0038240>>'s window is not equal to <UIAlertController: 0x101845c00>'s view's window!
2019-12-30 22:12:09.797048-0500 Project_Name[2813:268267] *** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:isFocused:notify:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit/UIKit-3698.34.4/UICollectionView.m:1980
2019-12-30 22:12:09.798240-0500 Project_Name[2813:268267] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'the collection view's data source did not return a valid cell from -collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath: for index path <NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000000016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x186687164 0x1858d0528 0x186687038 0x1870217f4 0x1906c80d0 0x18fc9e2ac 0x18fc98f68 0x18fc3c058 0x18a6c9948 0x18a6cdad0 0x18a63a31c 0x18a661b40 0x18fc31720 0x18662ecdc 0x18662c694 0x18662cc50 0x18654cc58 0x1883f6f84 0x18fca2804 0x1006020f8 0x18606c56c)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: well may be you forget to register your **reuseIdentifier** in collectionView

Comment: might I as what you mean by that?

Comment: try to add this line:=  

 `collectionView.registerClass(CustomCollectionViewCell
.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)`

into your **viewDidLoad** method

Answer (score 0):

You have some delegate functions that are incorrectly named from an old Swift version. Try the following instead:

```
override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 10
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! CustomCollectionViewCell

    // Configure the cell
    cell.label.text = "hi"
    return cell
}
```

Comment: If this answered your question, please mark it as the answer.

Comment: I fixed them per your recommendation but nothing has changed.

Comment: Did you set the reuseIdentifier in the collectionviewcell? Do you get a different error?

Answer (score 0):

As from your mentioned online resource, I think you are missing `CustomCollectionViewLayout` swift file in your project. Try to download project file from resource and check again

Comment: I can not find a file for the layout.  Is there a way I can make one?

Comment: As from your mentioned online resource they provide full code : https://github.com/kwandrews7/MultiDirectionCollectionView/tree/building-layout/MultiDirectionCollectionView Just compare with your code i think you are missing `CustomCollectionViewLayout` swift file